# Can't download google usb driver or android sdk

Tags: android

When I click the download button for the google usb driver or the android SDK manager it appears to go through the download process and then when it reaches 100% a window pops up with the big red X in the circle that says:

> `C:\Users\Daddy\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\GI088IDM\latest_usb_driver_windows.zip and then below that: Application not found.`

I'm trying to do this thing with my android phone to be able to move apps to the sd card without rooting the phone. Not really much of a techie but any advice would be appreciated. I have Windows 7.

Comment: maybe, quit using Internet Explorer, https://www.google.com/chrome

Comment: Not working in Chrome either except pop up now just says C:\users\daddy\downloads\latest_usb_driver_windows.zip